# How do I use a switch statement with while loop

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add a user to the Remote Desktop group using Powershell.

It seems it's not breaking the loop and doesn't execute further statements.

Can you please help me where the issue is:

```
$remote = ""
While($remote -ne "Y" ){
   $remote = read-host "Do you need to add anyone to the Remote Desktop group (y/n)?"
    Switch ($remote) 
        { 
            Y {
                $remoteuser = ""
                while ( ($remoteuser -eq "") -or ($UserExists -eq $false) )
                {
                $remoteuser = Read-Host "Enter the username that needs to be in the group"
                Write-Host "User inputted $remoteuser"
                sleep -Seconds 2

                try {
                        Get-ADUser -Identity $remoteuser -Server <server-FQDN>
                        $UserExists = $true
                        Write-Host "$remoteuser found!"
                        sleep 5
                    }
                catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityResolutionException]  {
                    Write-Host "User does not exist."
                    $UserExists = $false
                    }
                catch {
                    Write-Host "Username is blank"
                    $UserExists = $false
                    }
                }
            } 
            N {Write-Host "No user accounts will be added to the Remote Desktop Users group.  Restart your PC."}
             
            default {Write-Host "Only Y/N are Valid responses"}
        } 
        
        }
        
        <further statements>
```

Comment: Add `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Get-ADUser -Identity ...` statement to trigger the `catch` blocks

Comment: I'm going to guess it doesn't like your `While($remote -ne "Y")`. Personally I'd go with `Do{<switch stuff>}Until($Remote -match 'n')`.

Comment: Can you share sample output? I've tested the outer loop and can't reproduce your issue, and I don't have a suitable way to test your inner loop right now